# My app won´t work with old samsung devices

Tags: java, android, multithreading, operating-system

I had 8 smartphones to develop with; HTC M7, LG g3/s, LG g4, Samsung Galaxy S6, Samsung G Tab S1, Samsung Galaxy S8, Samsung Galaxy S7. I didn't have any problems in terms of performance or loading questions and answering them.

A few beta-testers told me that their devices won't work as they should. The funny part is, the devices are only old Samsung devices, every single one.

After you did an exam, a thread is running and it´s updating the SQL DB and set the exam to "finished"; 0 to 1. Which is not happening.

My app is targeted for version 4.0 up to the latest. And an old HTC M7 doesn't have a problem like this, it takes about 5 sek to handle the thread,  but it works just fine.

**Question:** Does Samsung handles Threads different than (more or less)native
Android, like HTC/LG's? Does Samsung stops threads, let's say after 3 Sek, unlike any other android which is running till exception or finishes?

If it's not like I've expected, what else could it be? Ram usage which is capped? Storage? Or do I have to add an:

```
 if(androidversion < 5.0){safe in foreground instead, don´t use thread;} //i know that this is not working.
```

Here is the code of the Thread:

```
public class PruefungKorrekturThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
ProgressDialog progressDialog4 ;
Context context ;
HpMobileSQLiteDB mobile ;
String id ;
List<tabelleUebungsfragen> mFrageList;
int richtig = 0 ;


public PruefungKorrekturThread(String id ,List<tabelleUebungsfragen> mFrageList , Context context)  {
    this.context = context ;
    this.id = id ;
    this.mFrageList = mFrageList ;
}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        mobile= new HpMobileSQLiteDB(context) ;
        long millis = new java.util.Date().getTime();
        mobile.updateNullRichtig(id) ;
        mobile.updateNullKorrigiert(id);
        mobile.updateUebungBeendetByID(id,String.valueOf(millis));
        richtig = mobile.getUebungErgebnisse(Integer.valueOf(id)) ;
        return "Executed";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (progressDialog4.isShowing()){progressDialog4.dismiss();}
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.dialog_box);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_pruefung_abgeben);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
        Button ja = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ja);
        TextView uebrig = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.uebrig) ;
        TextView abgeben = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pruefung_abgeben) ;
        abgeben.setText(context.getString(R.string.ierg));
        Button redirect = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.redirect);
        redirect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        redirect.setText(context.getString(R.string.zpl));
        redirect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent s = new Intent(context,Pruefungen.class) ;
                context.startActivity(s);
            }
        });
        Button nein = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nein);
        if (richtig>=45) {
            uebrig.setText(context.getString(R.string.dynstring9,richtig,mFrageList.size()));
            uebrig.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            mobile.updateUebungBestanden(id) ;
        } else {
            uebrig.setText(context.getString(R.string.dynstring10,richtig,mFrageList.size()));
            uebrig.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        ja.setText(context.getString(R.string.zK));
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        ja.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent s = new Intent(context, Pruefungen_view_pager.class);
                s.putExtra("is", "thema");
                s.putExtra("idsT",""+id) ;
                s.putExtra("thema_name","") ;
                s.putExtra("from","pruefungen") ;
                s.putExtra("themen_ergebnisse",""+"true") ;
                s.putExtra("erg_type","thema") ;
                context.startActivity(s);
            }
        });
        nein.setText(context.getString(R.string.zSs));
        nein.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_neutral);
        nein.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent s = new Intent(context,Homescreen.class) ;
                context.startActivity(s);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mobile  = new HpMobileSQLiteDB(context) ;
        progressDialog4 =  new  ProgressDialog(context,R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        if (progressDialog4.isShowing()){progressDialog4.dismiss();}
        progressDialog4.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog4.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog4.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog4.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.progress));
        progressDialog4.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

And it will get executed when the timer is `onfinish()`

```
 countDown = new CountDownTimer(Integer.valueOf(mobile.getUebungZeit(Integer.valueOf(topic))), 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                currentDowntimer = millisUntilFinished;
                if( type.equals("pruefungen")) {
                    long totals = (millisUntilFinished / 100) / 10;
                    long minutes = totals / 60;
                    long sek = totals % 60;
                    long min = minutes % 60;
                    long h = minutes / 60;
                    String timerString = String.format("%1$02d:%2$02d:%3$02d", h, min, sek);
                    timer.setText(timerString);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if( type.equals("pruefungen")) {
                    PruefungKorrekturThread ii = new PruefungKorrekturThread(topic, mFrageList, Pruefungen_view_pager.this);
                    ii.execute();
                }
                countDown.cancel();
                countisrunning = false;
            }
        };
```

When you are finished after you answered all questions and it is time left

```
 ja.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        countDown.onFinish();
                                    }
                                });
```

Edit*:

my company organized an S3 and i´ve got the problem now!

Samsung had a different threadment with Multiuserpermissions. At least till android 4.2! In 4.3 they made a hotfix which was a small update. Thats why some ppl, included me, can use the app on a factory reset S3 without any problems, but older devices with an upgraded 4.0-4.3 to 4.3 have problems with a multiuserexeption called:

```
 08-28 08:45:02.430 2345-2679/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                            java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
                                                at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
                                                at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
                                                at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
                                                at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Even after i´ve added this 2 Lines in Manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

and

```
 android:protectionLevel="signature"
```

and

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

in the proguard-rules.pro
this error still exists.

Comment: pls share your thread execution

Comment: I added the code as requiered.

Comment: what happens when your app goes into background, isn't htat a problem? Or what should that CountDownTimer do?

Comment: The countdowntimer pauses when you put the app in background. If you close the exam or app itself without finish the exam the "time-left" is getting safed in the db as well. But this is also not happening on old Samsung devices.. you know many people have them, but it's redicolous to buy an used s3 for 130 Bugs. Im a Student, won't/can´t afford more Smartphones :/